# Run function in parent component from child - React Navigator screen w/o redux

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react-native-i18n, react-native-popup-menu, react-navigation + expo (but I want eject soon). I want create settings screen when user can select language (autodetect or force: English, German etc.) and one-two other settings.

I'm trying using AsyncStorage to store user's preference.
When user change settings application I want set data in AsyncStorage and in state object in App.js (to refresh main component/full app if needed). But I have problem to using props.

App.js fragment:

```
const navOpt = ({ navigation }) => ({   
  headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'blue', elevation: null },
  headerRight: (<Menu>
    <MenuTrigger><MyIcon name="more" /></MenuTrigger>
    <MenuOptions>
      <MenuOption onSelect={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')} text='Settings' />
    </MenuOptions>
  </Menu>),
 });

const RootNav = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen }
}, {
  navigationOptions: navOpt
});


export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);      
    this.langHandler = this.langHandler.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      isLoadingComplete: false,
      currentLang: '',
      selectedLang: null,
      selectedTheme: null
    };
   }

  async componentWillMount() {    
    try {
    AsyncStorage.multiGet(['lang', 'theme'],   (err, stores) => {
        this.setState({ selectedLang: stores[0].lang });
        this.setState({ selectedTheme: stores[0].theme });    
    });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return;
    }

   try {
      await I18n.initAsync();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return;
    }
    console.log(this.state.selectedLang);
    if (this.state.selectedLang != null && this.state.selectedLang !== '') {
        this.setState({ currentLang: this.state.selectedLang });
        } else {
        this.setState({ currentLang: I18n.locale });
        }
    this.setState({ isLoadingComplete: true });   
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  langHandler(lang) {
    console.log(`xx${lang}`);
    this.setState({
        isLoadingComplete: false
    });
}

  render() {
  if (this.state.isLoadingComplete) return (<MenuProvider><RootNav /></MenuProvider>);
    return <View />;
  }
}
```

SettingsScreen.js - this is simplest version:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Button, TextInput, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

class SettingsScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Settings',
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: ''
    };
  }
    saveData() {
      AsyncStorage.setItem('lang', this.state.text);
      this.props.langHandler(this.state.text);
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View>
              <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text })} />
             <Button title='set' onPress={() => this.saveData()} />
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

I'm trying set something like

```
 const RootNav = StackNavigator({
      Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
      Settings: { screen: props => <SettingsScreen (...props) />}
```

But dosen't work.
Maybe I need use Redux? But if is possibility to avoid this is better :)
Maybe I should do all in different way?

Thank you for your time.
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`screenProps`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html#navigator-props). You have to add `langHandler` to `RootNav` screenProps.

```
render() {
  const screenProps = {
     langHandler: this.langHandler,
  };

  if (this.state.isLoadingComplete) {
    return (
       <MenuProvider>
          <RootNav screenProps={screenProps} />
      </MenuProvider>);

  }
  return <View />;
}
```

and then you'll be able to access `langHandler` using `this.props.screenProps.langHandler` in your `SettingsScreen`

```
saveData() {
  AsyncStorage.setItem('lang', this.state.text);
  this.props.screenProps.langHandler(this.state.text);
}
```